# Don't allow specific product quantities in the cart

Tags: php, woocommerce, conditional-statements, cart, checkout

We want the customers to only purchase the following quantities.

- 1 Bag
- 2 Bags
- 3 Bags
- 4 Bags
- 5 Bags
- 10 Bags

So, far; we've successfully managed to limit the number of quantities, that can be selected on the single product page,

We're currently using the following code to limit the user to a total of 10 Bags.

```
// Checking and validating when products are added to cart
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', 'only_six_items_allowed_add_to_cart', 10, 3 );

function only_six_items_allowed_add_to_cart( $passed, $product_id, $quantity ) {

$cart_items_count = WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count();
$total_count = $cart_items_count + $quantity;

if( $cart_items_count >= 10 || $total_count > 10 ){
    // Set to false
    $passed = false;
    // Display a message
     wc_add_notice( __( "Sorry, You can’t have more than 10 bags in your cart.", "woocommerce" ), 
"error" );
}
return $passed;
}
```

Now, we just need to add a condition, which will limit the user (and display a warning), whenever they try to increase their cart quantity, between the range of 6-9 bags.

The problem is that, for example, a customer adds 5 bags to their cart and after that, what if they go back and try to add another bag?

I want to avoid this situation, so the customer is only able to purchase the above-mentioned quantities.

Please check this link to better understand the situation:
https://mettaatta.com/product/metta-atta

Comment: ``if($total_count >=6 || $total_count <=9){
...
}``

Comment: How will they increase their cart quantity between 6-9 bags if you just don't allow it ? Use a drop-down list with options : 1 Bag
2 Bags
3 Bags
4 Bags
5 Bags
10 Bags

Comment: @vincentPHILIPPE They can go back to the single product page and then they will be able to add more products. 

I already have the dropdown list. 

The problem is that, for example, a customer adds 5 bags to their cart and after that, what if they go back and try to add another bag? I want to avoid this situation, so the customer is only able to purchase the above-mentioned quantities. 

Please check this link: https://mettaatta.com/product/metta-atta/

Comment: Ok I got it, so why not to check quantity like that ? ``if($total_count >=6 || $total_count <=9){ ... }``

Comment: @vincentPHILIPPE 

For some reason, if I add the above code, it won't let me even add a single item in the cart. It will always display the error, even if i add a single item

Comment: ```if($total_count >=6 && $total_count <=9){ ... }``` Sorry, my mistake. I put ``||`` instead of ``&&``

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one :

```
if($cart_items_count >= 10 || $total_count > 10 ){
    // Display a message
}
if($total_count >=6 && $total_count <=9){
   // Display a message
}
```

Will work as you need.

**EDIT**

If you want to combine them :

```
if(($cart_items_count >= 10 || $total_count > 10) || ($total_count >=6 && $total_count <=9)){
   // Display a message
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! 

Also, if want to display a different message for the second condition. Should I just redeclare the code again?

Comment: If you want two different message, you should'nt combine the two conditions.

Comment: Thank you very much! I really appreciate your help and support. Have a great day, ahead!